# CAST em várias colunas pra tirar a média

Tags: mysql, csv, cast

Tenho várias colunas em uma tabela csv, eu importei a tabela pra o mysql, mas quando importo pra o mysql tenho que fazer esta importação como varchar para todos os dados. Se eu fizer um CAST nestas colunas e depois tirar a média creio que dará certo o valor da média, porém, não sei como fazer.
Alguém pode ajudar?
Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou tirar a média sem fazer o CAST?

Comment: Eu tirei sim, inclusive deu certo, pois conferi junto com o Excel, porém, tem uma pessoa que é bastante experiente no mysql e disse que eu teria que fazer o cast.

Comment: Não seria `AVG(CAST(campo as SIGNED))`?

Comment: SELECT nome, CAST(AVG(cota_fpm) AS decimal(3,2)) AS cota_fpm 
FROM dadosv5
GROUP BY nome; - Seria assim então? Só que eu tenho várias colunas, tenho que fazer pra cada uma não é?

Comment: Craa, sou meio amador em MySQL, só sei o básico. Não conheço uma forma de fazer em tudo ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: tudo bem, te agradeço pela ajuda amigão. Vamos esperar pra ver se algum fera ai responde.